# Detect cookie deletion on the client

Tags: javascript, cookies

I've a Web Site that issues some cookies to the client (lifetime is 10 hours). However, if I open a site page and leave it for an hour or 1,5 hours untouched, I see that the cookie received from previously is not sent to the server again, it disappears from the client machine.
Is there any way to detect the moment, when the cookie is being deleted from the client machine?(e. g. per javascript).
Any help appreciable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.cookie` contains all cookies unless you're using HTTP-only-cookies (if you don't know what they are, you probably aren't using them).